# Editable table with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a table with TextBox or IText which can be edited with fabricjs.
I was able to create a table view by combining multiple Textboxes with background colours. according to the design, table should have rounded corners. Any Idea how to add those rounded corners?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using custom classes (Rect + TextBox) was able to find a solution for this.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')

fabric.RectWithText = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: 'rectWithText',
    text: null,
    textOffsetLeft: 0,
    textOffsetTop: 0,
    _prevObjectStacking: null,
    _prevAngle: 0,
    
    type: "roundedRect",
  topLeft: this.topLeft || [0,0],
  topRight: this.topRight  || [0,0],
  bottomLeft: this.bottomLeft  || [0,0],
  bottomRight: this.bottomRight  || [0,0],

  _render: function(ctx) {
    var w = this.width,
      h = this.height,
      x = -this.width / 2,
      y = -this.height / 2,
      /* "magic number" for bezier approximations of arcs (http://itc.ktu.lt/itc354/Riskus354.pdf) */
      k = 1 - 0.5522847498;
    ctx.beginPath();

    // top left
    ctx.moveTo(x + this.topLeft[0], y);

    // line to top right
    ctx.lineTo(x + w - this.topRight[0], y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w - k * this.topRight[0], y, x + w, y + k * this.topRight[1], x + w, y + this.topRight[1]);

    // line to bottom right
    ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h - this.bottomRight[1]);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + w, y + h - k * this.bottomRight[1], x + w - k * this.bottomRight[0], y + h, x + w - this.bottomRight[0], y + h);

    // line to bottom left
    ctx.lineTo(x + this.bottomLeft[0], y + h);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x + k * this.bottomLeft[0], y + h, x, y + h - k * this.bottomLeft[1], x, y + h - this.bottomLeft[1]);

    // line to top left
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + this.topLeft[1]);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, y + k * this.topLeft[1], x + k * this.topLeft[0], y, x + this.topLeft[0], y);

    ctx.closePath();

    this._renderPaintInOrder(ctx);
  },
  
    recalcTextPosition: function () {
      const sin = Math.sin(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle))
      const cos = Math.cos(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle))
      const newTop = sin * this.textOffsetLeft + cos * this.textOffsetTop
      const newLeft = cos * this.textOffsetLeft - sin * this.textOffsetTop
      const rectLeftTop = this.getPointByOrigin('left', 'top')
      this.text.set('left', rectLeftTop.x + newLeft)
      this.text.set('top', rectLeftTop.y + newTop)
    },
    
    initialize: function (rectOptions, textOptions, text) {
      this.callSuper('initialize', rectOptions)
      this.text = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
        ...textOptions,
        selectable: false,
        evented: false,
      })
      this.textOffsetLeft = this.text.left - this.left
      this.textOffsetTop = this.text.top - this.top
      this.on('moving', () => {
        this.recalcTextPosition()
      })
      this.on('rotating', () => {
        this.text.rotate(this.text.angle + this.angle - this._prevAngle)
        this.recalcTextPosition()
        this._prevAngle = this.angle
      })
      this.on('scaling', (e) => {
        this.recalcTextPosition()
      })
      this.on('added', () => {
        this.canvas.add(this.text)
      })
      this.on('removed', () => {
        this.canvas.remove(this.text)
      })
      this.on('mousedown:before', () => {
        this._prevObjectStacking = this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking
        this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true
      })
      this.on('mousedblclick', () => {
        this.text.selectable = true
        this.text.evented = true
        this.canvas.setActiveObject(this.text)
        this.text.enterEditing()
        this.selectable = false
      })
      this.on('deselected', () => {
        this.canvas.preserveObjectStacking = this._prevObjectStacking
      })
      this.text.on('editing:exited', () => {
        this.text.selectable = false
        this.text.evented = false
        this.selectable = true
      })
    }
})

const rectOptions = {
  left: 10,
  topLeft: [20,20],
  top: 10,
  width: 200,
  height: 75,
  fill: 'rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3)',
  rx: 10
}
const textOptions = {
  left: 35,
  top: 30,
  width: 150,
  fill: 'white',
  shadow: new fabric.Shadow({
    color: 'rgba(34, 34, 100, 0.4)',
    blur: 2,
    offsetX: -2,
    offsetY: 2
  }),
  fontSize: 30,
  selectable: true
}
const rectWithText = new fabric.RectWithText(rectOptions, textOptions, 'Some text')
canvas.add(rectWithText)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.2.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```